# Get contact list and check if contacts have app installed like WhatsApp does

Tags: iphone, ios, installation, contacts

I'm working on an app that creates an user profile. I need to be able to see who from my contacts has the app installed so that i am able to grant them access to my profile and see their profiles.

How do i get the full contact list, determine my phone number to create my account with it, and check how many people from the contacts have the app installed? (similar to how WhatsApp does it)

I know it's possible to get the contact list by using Apple API's, but do i have to send all the information to the server to check if they have the app installed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you would have to send the data to a server.
First you would ask the user for their number, then upload the contact list, and compare the list with the users already on your server.

I'd recommend you don't transfer the numbers themselves to your server, either encrypt the data transfer, or use something like a hash function before sending/storing, to ensure that their is some privacy/security for your users.